# how to get highlighted text positions using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a text highlighter. below is the example of the html structure.

```
<div id="donthighlight">Sea no iuvaret epicurei conceptam, id dicunt sensibus expetenda</div>
<div id="highlightarea">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an zril splendide est, discere accusam</div>
```

If I select the word "Lorem" from the second div, I should be able to capture the starting character position and ending character position, and add a span tag around it with a class. this will highlight the background of the text temporarily. function should only work within the second div.

I Also want to save those character positions in DB, so that the next time user visit the same article I should be able show the previously highlighted parts. Also user should be able to remove highlights.

I tried a few jquery plugins and was unable complete my requirements. How can I make this work? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found exactly what I was looking for. find the link below to the plugin

http://annotatorjs.org/

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are searching for this.. under getSelectionCharOffsetsWithin return place, you can do your further tasks, you can fetch the word by its position and then save that word to db using ajax calls... You can give strict code for highlighting word only in parent div ..

```
<input type="button" onclick="alertSelection()" unselectable="on" value="Get selection">
<div id="main"> <div>hi</div> <div>dude!</div> </div>
<script>
function getSelectionCharOffsetsWithin(element) {
var start = 0, end = 0;
var sel, range, priorRange;
if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
    range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    priorRange = range.cloneRange();
    priorRange.selectNodeContents(element);
    priorRange.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
    start = priorRange.toString().length;
    end = start + range.toString().length;
}else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" &&
    (sel = document.selection).type != "Control") {
    range = sel.createRange();
    priorRange = document.body.createTextRange();
    priorRange.moveToElementText(element);
    priorRange.setEndPoint("EndToStart", range);
    start = priorRange.text.length;
    end = start + range.text.length;
}
    return {
    start: start,
    end: end
    };
}
function alertSelection() {
var mainDiv = document.getElementById("main");
var sel = getSelectionCharOffsetsWithin(mainDiv);
alert(sel.start + ": " + sel.end);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I found this earlier and now am trying to modify the code but the position value is coming from the entire html not from the specific div

Comment: See we are fetching Id from main div, did you tried changing id from "main" to your required div id ?

var mainDiv = document.getElementById("main");

Comment: Firstly thank you for the reply. I found exactly what I was looking for with some extra features and I posted my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

check this below fiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/satishkumar_kt/20863oob/1/

check `replaceSelectedText` function in it

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but it's a bit different from what I want to achieve